# Can't call Swift function from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have this static function in a Swift class that I'd like to call in Objective-C:

```
static internal func photoActionSheet<T:UIViewController where T:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, T:UINavigationControllerDelegate>(hostAndDelegateViewController:T)
```

I have other functions from the class that I'm able to call from ObjC, but it doesn't know of just this one

Thanks

Comment: May be because it's `internal`?

Comment: Nope...the other functions are internal as well and they're ok.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you would remove that downvote. I'm trying to build up my rep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions with generic type constraints cannot be exported to Objective-C.

As a workaround, you could define the function like below and check for protocol conformance inside the function implementations:

```
static internal func photoActionSheet(hostAndDelegateViewController: UIViewController) {
  guard let vc = hostAndDelegateViewController as? protocol<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> else {
    fatalError("hostAndDelegateViewController must conform UINavigationControllerDelegate and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate")
  }

  // let picker = UIImagePickerController()
  // picker.delegate = vc
}
```

Likewise, Objective-C type `UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> *` will be exported to Swift as `UIViewController!`

Comment: Good to know. However, if I define the Swift function like what you did, I wouldn't be able to assign the UIViewController as a delegate of a UIImagePickerController (because it needs the two protocols) correct?

Comment: @theNotSoPro It can be done with a type cast trick. I've updated my answer.